# Why is there a mismatch in base85 between Dart and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dart, base85

**Python code**

```
from base64 import b85decode
from base64 import b85encode
encoded=b85encode(b'Hello, world!!!!')
print(encoded.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output:

`'NM&qnZ!92pZ*pv8At50l'`

**Dart code**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:base85/base85.dart';

void main() {
  var codec = Base85Codec(Alphabets.z85);
  var encode = codec.encode(Uint8List.fromList('Hello, world!!!!'.codeUnits));
  print(encode);
}
```

Output:

`nm=QNz.92Pz/PV8aT50L`

Letter case is swapped between upper and lower, and non-letters are also mapped differently.

I may be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are not actually using ascii85 in the dart example at all.  Compare this (requires `pip install pyzmq`*):

```py
from zmq.utils import z85
z85.encode(b"Hello, world!!!!")
#  b'nm=QNz.92Pz/PV8aT50L'
```

z85 and ascii85 are subtly different.

*`pip show zmq` reveals: `Summary: You are probably looking for pyzmq... Requires: pyzmq`.  Thanks to @SumitKumar for the catch.

### References:

https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec/32/

Comment: `pip install pyzmq` will give the latest version of the library.